# Serve multiple pages from 1 PHP file?

Tags: php

So basically i am struggling with the need of optimizing my code for some project of mine.
Currently i have pages like `add_company.php`, `view_company.php`, `edit_company.php`.

What i would like to do is to serve all content from just 1 PHP file `company.php`.
So to speak `company.php?action=view`, `company.php?action=edit` etc. Is the only way to do this with massive if else statements? That would make my `company.php` like mega huge.

**Or maybe even better how could I serve all my pages just using index.php ?**

So what would be the best way to accomplish this? I am not php guru and i don't have much experience with MVC or any other pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably use HTML caching. That way it doesn't matter how you structure you PHP files. - For example, take a look at [ **this question** ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223/how-do-i-implement-a-html-cache-for-a-php-site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make `company.php`

```
<?php

$allowed = array('add', 'view', 'edit');

if ( ! isset($_GET['action'])) {
   die('missing param');
}

$action = $_GET['action'];

if ( ! in_array($action, $allowed)) {
   die('invalid');
}



require $action . '_' . __FILE__;
```

Quick and dirty, but should work :) You could place this code in any file, and it will work straight away.

With a bit of modification, you could make this your front controller with `index.php`.

Comment: `if ( ! isset($_GET['edit']))` shouldnt that be `if ( ! isset($_GET['action']))` ?

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer using a switch statement for the $_GET variable. Its my personal preference to put all the logic pertaining to one entity (in this case company) in a single PHP file because I generally deal with tons of entities. If you want a MVC model, this might not be what you are looking for. Just my 2 cents.

```
// Common page header
// Other stuff common in the pages

$page_to_load = $_GET[view];

switch($page_to_load) {

case 'view':
//Logic to view or HTML for view
break;

case 'add':
//Logic to add or HTML for add
break;

}
// Common footer etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple stuff. It should look something like this:

```
//index.php
if (!isset($_GET['page']))
    {
    require('index_contents.php');
    }
else if ($_GET['page'] == 'company')
    {
    if (!isset($_GET['action']))
        {
        require('company_contents.php');
        }
    else if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit')
        {
        require('edit_company.php');
        }
    else if ($_GET['action'] == 'add')
        {
        require('add_company.php');
        }
    else
        {
        require('company_contents.php');
        }
    }
else
    {
    require('index_contents.php');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy solution would be to just use includes.

```
if ($_GET["action"] == "view") {
  require("action_view.php");
} else if ...
```

(of course, you might want to use a switch statement, if you have lots of different page types)

Then action_view.php contains just the code for the specific page.

Better, but also more complicated solutions, would be an object oriented approach (abstract Page class with Factory Pattern) or forthright a good framework and template engine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use POST instead of GET with index.php:

```
<?php

require($_POST['action'] . ".php");

?>
```

This would hide the action type from the user, acting as though it is a single page. However, it may require using a form in your navigation as opposed to linking direct to "company.php?action=edit".

Comment: [Not secure enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal). Hackers could include any PHP file. Also, I think he wants to use GET.

Comment: @alex Thanks for letting me know - handy link.

Comment: No worries :) See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783550/serve-multiple-pages-from-1-php-file/3783561#3783561) for how I handled the problem in this situation.