# Multiple HTML Pages in one file

Tags: php, html

Hi guys I am making a website for a school project, but to keep in organised, I want to have all pages in one document, and when you go to the site the default page is index.php, and the other pages are linked like this: `index.php?p=page`
the problem now is, that I had this script, but don't know where I have it. I'm not skilled in PHP too, I got it from a friend of mine. It was like this:

```
?>
<php? some php code ?>
<html tag etc>
<head> Head stuff </head>
<Nav> <Header>
<php? some php code where I filled in what the link was of the content under         it ?>
< The content of the page, excluding the header, navigator etc because that   was above here. > 

?>

Then I could do the same thing over and over again, and just change the PHP   code and it worked. 

<footer stuff>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that there are many scripts for this, and I searched Google for over an hour, but with no succes.

-Tristan

Comment: You're looking for something like this: `if (isset($_GET['page']) && ($_GET['page'] == 'something')`

Comment: `<php?` should be `<?php`.

Comment: Now how exactly am I supposed to put that in the site? Could you give me a full example, because I'm a complete PHP noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic example of how it works :

```
<?php

$page = $_GET['page'];

if ( $page == 'one' ) {
    echo 'This is page one!';
} elseif ( $page == 'two' ) {
    echo 'This is page to';
}

// http://yoursite.com/index.php?page=one
// Outputs 'This is page one!'
```

Learn little more about GET request right here : [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:
[Serve multiple pages from 1 PHP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783550/serve-multiple-pages-from-1-php-file)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783550/serve-multiple-pages-from-1-php-file)

If you want to make something like youtube.com/?watch=XXXXXXXXX
so you need just to change XXXXXXXXX to display multiple content.

but you still can use :

1. One-page navigation system.
2. Display / Hides Pages With JS

Example Of JavaScript:

we have website1 as a website

we have a - b - c - d as pages

js will hide all pages exept the page you want to show.