# How can i host one html file more than one?

Tags: php, html, hosting

I am new to web design. I'm trying to make a restaurant management system. Customers will scan the qr code and the menu will be shown to the customer. I need to host a menu more than one (like [www.site.com/?id=1](http://www.site.com/?id=1), [www.site.com/?id=2](http://www.site.com/?id=2) ... on wamp or xampp) but I don't know how.

Comment: Well if you make two PHP or HTML pages with different names, then you can put them on the same site. You can put as many as you want. `www.example.com/menu1.html`, `www.example.com/menu2.html`, etc.

Comment: great but how can i do it?

Comment: <?php

isset($_REQUEST['1']) and (function(){
 echo '1 !!!!!';
})();
isset($_REQUEST['2']) and (function(){
 echo '2 !!!'; 
})();
?>

Comment: huh? I just said, create two files with diffeernt names.

Comment: But if you want to do it via URL querystring in a single PHP script instead, then look for `$_REQUEST['id']` - in `id=1`, `id` is the name of the parameter. `1` is the value of the parameter. When you write `$_REQUEST['id']` you're asking PHP to give you "the value of the request parameter whose name is 'id'". Does that make sense now? So you can simply write `echo $_REQUEST["id"];` to show the value which was submitted in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, I had this same question about six years ago. You can find the answers here:

[Multiple HTML Pages in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975045/multiple-html-pages-in-one-file)

In short, what you want is to make use of the `$_GET[]` variable in PHP.

For example:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])) { 
   $id = $_GET["id"]; 
   echo $id;
}
```

With a request to `index.php?id=1`
will echo back `1`

Comment: i tried but its not working most probably mistake is mine. Can you explain this more simple for me?

Comment: @Asid There isn't really a simpler way of explaining this. All you have to do is exactly what is shown here. If it's somehow not working for you, you need to update your question to show us precisely what _you_ tried, and exactly what error or unexpected output you received when you tried it. "not working" doesn't tell us anything useful about your problem.