# Cache html page but not data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have html_page.php that contains my html page,
javascript.js contains ajax to call process.php which lookup data from MySQL and populate into html_page.php.
Is it possible for me to cache the HTML structure of html_page.php but not the data in the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to give you a proper answer without you giving us a context you are working on, but according to your question tags, I assume you are talking about using PHP.

You should refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223/how-do-i-implement-a-html-cache-for-a-php-site) on implementing caching on a PHP site.

Typically, you will need to use plugins and extensions that don't come out-of-the-box with PHP.
Some web servers also have caching functionality built into them, you should look up the documentation of your web server.